# Three.js | Unable to access imported object property outside loader.load

Tags: three.js

I want to move an imported object(.obj) on every render/animate function call. 
So, I made a copy of the object so as to access it outside the `loader.load` but everytime I call `companion.position` I'm getting this error. ( `companion` is a global variable )

[image]

Also, I tried `object.traverse` in render function and I got the same error (traverse got replaced with position in error).

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Following is where I'm loading the obj and copying it to `companion`.

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

mtlLoader.setPath( 'obj/' );
mtlLoader.load( 'satellite.mtl', function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( 'obj/' );
    objLoader.load( 'satellite.obj', function( object ) {

        object.position.z = 300;
        object.scale.set( 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 );
        object.rotation.y = Math.PI;

        object.traverse( function( child ) { 

            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 

                child.castShadow = true;
                if ( child.material !== undefined ) child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

            }
        });

        companion = object;
        scene.add( object );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
var parent = new THREE.Group();
scene.add( parent );
```

In your load code replace

```
// companion = object;
// scene.add( object )
// with
parent.add( object ); // will add the object to the parent but also to the scene
```

then in your `animate()` function you can do something like:

```
parent.position.x = ....
```

Comment: Your approach helped. But instead of `THREE.Group` I used Object3D. 
Yayy Thanks :D